# Разделение гит репозитория на 2 части

Tags: android, git, git-branch

Всем привет. Есть гит репо. Как я могу разделить содержимое на 2 части и работать с ними раздельно? Вот, эти два пакета надо разделить: https://github.com/D330/Skyscrapers/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ru/flippy/skyscrapers

Я так понял, нужно все удалить, создать вторую ветку и делать коммиты в обе? Тогда как делать коммиты в разные ветки, если эти два пакета - неразделимы в проекте?

Comment: А не проще репозиторий новый создать?

Comment: @ahgpoug, всмысле, отдельный репозиторий куда коммитить вторую часть?) Ну, это как-то не то. Может, проще, но хочется именно с ветками поработать

Comment: Выносишь отсюда SDK и работаешь с ним в отдельном репозитории. По идее, его можно как библиотеку оформить и подключать уже к проекту. Как сделать - не знаю, просто додумка. Работать отдельно с 2 частями проекта в одном репозитории вряд ли получится.

Comment: @ahgpoug, точно. SDK можно как библу подрубить. Спасибо за идею! Но все таки ответ на вопрос хотелось бы узнать

Comment: Мне кажется, вариант с библиотекой будет самым разумным вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

Вам достаточно создать новый модуль типа `Android library` в проекте (назовите его, например, `sdk`)
Далее переносите код вашего sdk в новый модуль, а модулю `app` прописываете в зависимости модуль `sdk`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':sdk')
    ...
}
```